# Add content after product thumbnail gallery

Tags: php, woocommerce, hook, product, thumbnails

I'm trying to add content under product images (under thumbnail). With these :

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_thumbnails ' , 'new_add_below_prod_gallery', 5 );
function new_add_below_prod_gallery() {
   echo '<div class="woocommerce-product-gallery" style="clear:both;">';
   echo '<span><html>
<head>
<style>
.infoplus {
    border-right: 2px solid black;
    height: auto;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -3px;
    top: 0;
    background-color: #FCFCFC;
    padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="infoplus">
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry’s standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. </p>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html></span>';
   echo '</div>';
    echo '<br>';
}
```

But it doesn't work unless only the main image is displayed. When the other images appear and the thumbnail is created, the text disappears.

With all other hooks it works, only with "woocommerce_product_thumbnails" not.
What I want is to fill the space below the product images, because the right column is longer.

What is the right hook for this situation?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override `product-image.php` to your theme.

Copy `product-image.php` from here.

```
`wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/single-product/product-image.php`;
```

And upload here to your currently active theme dir.

```
`wp-content/themes/yourthemename/woocommerce/single-product/product-image.php`;
```

Now your add code to that file.

```
<?php
/**
 * Single Product Image
 *
 * This template can be overridden by copying it to yourtheme/woocommerce/single-product/product-image.php.
 *
 * HOWEVER, on occasion WooCommerce will need to update template files and you
 * (the theme developer) will need to copy the new files to your theme to
 * maintain compatibility. We try to do this as little as possible, but it does
 * happen. When this occurs the version of the template file will be bumped and
 * the readme will list any important changes.
 *
 * @see     https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/
 * @package WooCommerce\Templates
 * @version 3.5.1
 */

defined( 'ABSPATH' ) || exit;

// Note: `wc_get_gallery_image_html` was added in WC 3.3.2 and did not exist prior. This check protects against theme overrides being used on older versions of WC.
if ( ! function_exists( 'wc_get_gallery_image_html' ) ) {
    return;
}

global $product;

$columns           = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_product_thumbnails_columns', 4 );
$post_thumbnail_id = $product->get_image_id();
$wrapper_classes   = apply_filters(
    'woocommerce_single_product_image_gallery_classes',
    array(
        'woocommerce-product-gallery',
        'woocommerce-product-gallery--' . ( $post_thumbnail_id ? 'with-images' : 'without-images' ),
        'woocommerce-product-gallery--columns-' . absint( $columns ),
        'images',
    )
);
?>
<div class="<?php echo esc_attr( implode( ' ', array_map( 'sanitize_html_class', $wrapper_classes ) ) ); ?>" data-columns="<?php echo esc_attr( $columns ); ?>" style="opacity: 0; transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;">
    <figure class="woocommerce-product-gallery__wrapper">
        <?php
        if ( $post_thumbnail_id ) {
            $html = wc_get_gallery_image_html( $post_thumbnail_id, true );
        } else {
            $html  = '<div class="woocommerce-product-gallery__image--placeholder">';
            $html .= sprintf( '<img src="%s" alt="%s" class="wp-post-image" />', esc_url( wc_placeholder_img_src( 'woocommerce_single' ) ), esc_html__( 'Awaiting product image', 'woocommerce' ) );
            $html .= '</div>';
        }

        echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_single_product_image_thumbnail_html', $html, $post_thumbnail_id ); // phpcs:disable WordPress.XSS.EscapeOutput.OutputNotEscaped

        do_action( 'woocommerce_product_thumbnails' );
        ?>
    </figure>
    <div class="infoplus">
        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry’s standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Also, you need to add custom js because your content will appear top of the gallery due to gallery load. so we have to store that HTML in var and remove it after it then appends it to the gallery.

```
function add_custom_js(){
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        (function($){
            $(document).ready(function($) {
                setTimeout(function(){
                    var infoplus = $(".infoplus")[0].outerHTML;
                    $(".infoplus").remove();
                    $('.woocommerce-product-gallery').append(infoplus);
                },100);
            });
        })(jQuery);
    </script>
    <?php
}

add_action( 'wp_footer', 'add_custom_js', 10 );
```

**Tested and works**

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your response and involvement. I notice that your code works in your print screen, I assume it's a storefront. I tried to do this but in my case I failed. I couldn't find product-image.php in the wp-content of the theme. I searched for other syntaxes, .class, ... hooks, ... but I couldn't find the similarities.
My theme is: https://dessign.net/virtualstore/

Comment: I couldn't find product-image.php in the wp-content of the theme.
=> You have to copy from the plugin. read the second line of my answer.

Comment: Sorry, my typo, I don't have the single-product folder to copy there. I have a single-product.php file.

Comment: Are you sure? please share screenshots?

Comment: You are showing me the theme path. You need to copy the file from here - `wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/single-product/product-image.php`; and upload here - `wp-content/themes/yourthemename/woocommerce/single-product/product-image.php`;

Comment: Yes. It works perfectly for me too. Thank you very much for your help and involvement.